# Is there a way to configure Team Explorer Everywhere Checkin Policies via Cross-Platform Command Line?

Tags: tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

Right now we are using the Cross-Platform CLI for Team Explorer Everywhere to do work on Linux. I want to have a check-in policy that forces users to add a comment to their checkin. Based on this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg475890(v=vs.100).aspx it seems like if I use the web interface or Visual Studio, or Visual Studio Command Line these policies won't apply. However, this page doesn't seem to give any information on how to do it using the command line and I can't find info anywhere else. Is there a way I can do this via the Linux command line or even a standalone app, or do I have to use Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Team Explorer Everywhere (TEE) Command-Line Client (CLC) cannot configure check-in policies and the TEE Eclipse plug-in *must* be used.